# Is it possible to locate a star glyph on a scatterplot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, glyph

This `R` code outputs 5 `star glyphs` but I can't control their location:

```
stars(mtcars[1:5, 1:4], key.loc = c(6, 0.5),
      main = "Example of 4 glyph stars", labels= NULL, flip.labels = FALSE)
```

I want to position each glyph according to 5 pairs of (x,y) coordinates on a scatterplot using `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do it using ggplot, but `stars` has the capability to control the location by using `locations`. See below:

```
x_s <- 1:5
y_s <- 1:5
loc <- data.frame(x = x_s, y = y_s)

stars(mtcars[1:5, 1:4], key.loc = c(5, 0), locations = loc,
  main = "Example of 4 glyph stars", labels = NULL, flip.labels = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is enough for building a scatterplot.